# Elixir - try/catch vs try/rescue?

Tags: elixir

## Background

Both `try/rescue` and `try/catch` are error handling techniques in Elixir. According the [corresponding chapter](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/try-catch-and-rescue.html) in the introduction guide.

> Errors can be rescued using the `try/rescue` construct

On the other hand,

> `throw` and `catch` are reserved for situations where it is not possible to retrieve a value unless by using `throw` and `catch`.

## Doubts

I have a brief understanding that `rescue` is for errors. While `catch` is for any value.

However,

- When should I make use of the error handling mechanisms in Elixir?
- What are the differences between them in detail?
- How should I pick one to use in a specific use case?
- What exactly are *'the situations where it is not possible to retrieve a value unless by using `throw` and `catch`'*?

Comment: You shouldn't use them at all ;) It's not a Java that you want to `try/catch` all errors. You should use supervisors when error occured to make your app robust or use raise whenever error should occur.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which Situations Require Throw/Catch In Elixir?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36036480/which-situations-require-throw-catch-in-elixir)

Comment: Besides the accepted answer, the table at [the answer by Dimagog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49524869/1460448) is great.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It's a good question.After research a bit.

- What is the differences between them in details?

  José's answer:

> Mainly, you should use `throw` for control-flow and reserve `raise` for errors, which happens on developer mistakes or under exceptional circumstances.
>
> In Elixir, this distinction is rather theoretical, but they matter in
>   some languages like Ruby, where using errors/exceptions for
>   control-flow is expensive because creating the exception object and
>   backtrace is expensive.

- How should I pick one to use in a specific use case?

Please check this answer [Which situations require throw catch in Elixir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36036480/which-situations-require-throw-catch-in-elixir)

Shortly:

`raise/rescue`

Consider raise/rescue to be explicitly about exception handling (some unexpected situation like programmer errors, wrong environment, etc).

`throw/catch`

Is useful in places where you have expected failures.
Classic examples are:

- exiting a deeply nested recursive call:
  https://github.com/devinus/poison/blob/master/lib/poison/parser.ex#L34-L46
- normal error handling is too expensive (can occur in too many
  places):
  https://github.com/michalmuskala/mongodb_ecto/blob/master/lib/mongo_ecto/objectid.ex#L29-L43
- you have an non-local construct (like transactions):
  https://github.com/elixir-lang/ecto/blob/428126157b1970d10f9d5233397f07c35ce69cac/test/support/test_repo.exs#L84-L98

The last one:

- What exactly are 'the situations where it is not possible to retrieve a value unless by using throw and catch'?

Let's say you are trying to running some code from a process that is supervised by a `Supervisor` but the process dies for an unexpected reason.

```
try do
IO.inspect MayRaiseGenServer.maybe_will_raise
rescue
  RuntimeError -> IO.puts "there was an error"
end
```

`MayRaiseGenServer` is supervised by a `Supervisor` and for some reason an error was raised:

```
try do
IO.inspect MayRaiseGenServer.maybe_will_raise # <- Code after this line is no longer executed
```

And then you can come up with using catch an exception here:

```
try do
  IO.inspect MayRaiseGenServer.maybe_will_raise
catch
  :exit, _ -> IO.puts "there was an error"
end
```

Ok.Hope that clarify enough what we are looking for.

Answer (score 39):

Other answers already cover usage of `raise` vs. `throw` well.

I'll describe the *mechanics* of how to handle each exceptional situation using a table:

```
creating | handling with  | where y is
-----------------------------------------------------
raise x  | rescue y       | %RuntimeError{message: x}
error(x) | rescue y       | %ErlangError{original: x}
throw x  | catch y        | x
exit(x)  | catch :exit, y | x
```

where `error(x)` is actually `:erlang.error(x)`.

On top of this, both `rescue` and `catch/1` (catch with 1 argument) are just a syntactic sugar. All 4 cases above could be handled with `catch/2`:

```
creating | handling with | where y is | and z is
-----------------------------------------------------------------
raise x  | catch y, z    | :error     | %RuntimeError{message: x}
error(x) | catch y, z    | :error     | x
throw x  | catch y, z    | :throw     | x
exit(x)  | catch y, z    | :exit      | x
```

**Note the asymmetry** of handling `raise` and `error` with `rescue` vs. `catch/2`: `x` is wrapped into `%ErlangError` when `rescue` is used, but not with `catch/2`.

Comment: The table showing all cases is fantastic. I was always confused about rescue/catch, and the fact you can use catch/1 or catch/2. That cleared it. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, truly a great and very terse answer. Thanks!

Comment: This table is very helpful. I think the chapter of the official guide on this topic has been quite confusing. The important takeaway is that everything can boil down to `catch/2`.

Comment: It helped me handle exceptions raised at the database.

Answer (score 4):

I like to use the analogy:

You either `catch` a thrown ball or `rescue` someone from a mountain.

- `catch` - is expected and used for control flow (e.g. Java-like error handling)
- `rescue` - for unexpected errors (e.g. runtime errors)

Answer (score 3):

`try/catch` has to be used when an error is known (like request validation errors) and `raise/rescue` has to be used to catch exceptions (exceptions are unknown or unhandled errors).

A combination of both of these can be used. For example,

```
def example(conn, params) do 
    try do
      data  = %{}
      types = %{field1: :string, field2: :integer}
  
      changeset =
        {data, types}
        |> cast(params, [:field1, :field2])
        |> validate_required([:field1, :field2])

      if (!changeset.valid?) do
        throw({:ClientError, changeset.errors })
      end
      
      # some logic
      
      raise ArgumentError
    catch
      # client error is caught here
      {:ClientError, error} ->
        IO.inspect(error, label: "client error")
    rescue
      exception ->
        # Argument error is caught here
        IO.inspect(exception, label: "exception") 
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

By reading Dimagog's answer, and the article found at https://inquisitivedeveloper.com/lwm-elixir-48/, I really gained a lot of insight on the matter. I am just sharing a personal practical example,

```
chset = 
  %SomeModel{}
  |> SomeModel.changeset(attrs)
try do 
  chset
  |> Repo.insert()
catch :error,  %Postgrex.Error{postgres: %{code: :invalid_password}} ->
  { :error ,
    chset
    |> Changeset.add_error(:username, "may be invalid")
    |> Changeset.add_error(:password, "may be invalid")
  }
else    
  {:ok, lr} -> {:ok, Map.put(lr, :password, nil)}
  error -> error
end
```

The postgresql error code comes from a `plpgsql` function in which I raise an error, as follows,

```
 raise invalid_password using
   message = 'Invalid username or password' , 
   detail = 'A user could not be found that matched the supplied username and password';
```