# Elixir: rescue/catch task timeout

Tags: elixir

I have the following code:

```
try do
  IO.inspect("start task")
  t = Task.async(fn -> Process.sleep(7000)  end)
  IO.inspect("start awaiting")
  Task.await(t)
rescue
  e ->
    IO.inspect("catch error")
    IO.inspect(e)
after
  IO.inspect("after")
end
IO.inspect("success ending")
```

That will print:

```
"start task"
"start awaiting"
"after"

00:00:03.510 [info]  Application my_app exited: exited in: MyApp.Application.start(:normal, [])
** (EXIT) exited in: Task.await(%Task{owner: #PID<0.497.0>, pid: #PID<0.498.0>, ref: #Reference<0.3923892342.570949633.190577>}, 5000)
    ** (EXIT) time out
```

So await crashes my caller process, and I can't rescue the error, by somehow the "after" block is used. I don't understand how I can protect my caller process from a task timeout error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are going to want to use `try/catch` in this particular instance.

```
try do
  IO.inspect("start task")
  t = Task.async(fn -> Process.sleep(7000)  end)
  IO.inspect("start awaiting")
  Task.await(t)
catch
  :exit, _ -> IO.puts "caught exit"
after
  IO.inspect("after")
end
IO.inspect("success ending")
```

---

```
"start task"
"start awaiting"
caught exit
"after"
"success ending"
```

The differences between the two can be found in various places. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36036480/which-situations-require-throw-catch-in-elixir) may be a good start.